# Using VBA Find What:= to retrieve a value in a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

First thanks to everyone, you've been a tremendous support in getting me in shape with my really naive VBA code. As I'm advancing, I'm running into new issues.

My challenge is that I'm using this code to find a value in all open workbooks. If it's found, the remaining code executes. I want the found value to be easily changeable by my end users, without them getting into the code. So, I've added a new sheet to `ThisWorkbook` called `Data Specs`. I want that when my code starts to find something, it should look for whatever the value is in this sheet in cell `A2`.

```
Sheets("Add File Here").Select
If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then
    Worksheets("Master Mapper").Activate

    Dim answer003 As Integer
    answer003 = MsgBox("Please check the Data Sheet. No value found in first row! Do you wish to find Cvent003 file in open workbooks and start process?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Review & Proceed")
    If answer003 = vbYes Then
'Starts here
        Dim wSheet As Worksheet
        Dim wBook As Workbook
        Dim rFound As Range
        Dim bFound As Boolean
        Dim lngLastRow2 As Long
        Dim Cvent003Val As Long
        Cvent003Val = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Cells("A2").Value
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each wBook In Application.Workbooks
            For Each wSheet In wBook.Worksheets
                Set rFound = Nothing
                Set rFound = wSheet.Range("D1:D2").Find(What:=Cvent003Val, SearchFormat:=True, After:=wSheet.Range("D1"), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)

'rFound.Cells.Select
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    bFound = True
                    Application.Goto rFound, True
'Rows(1, 2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    lngLastRow2 = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                    Range("A1:G" & lngLastRow2).Copy
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add File Here").Activate
                    Range("A1").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Exit For
                End If

                Next wSheet
                If bFound = True Then Exit For
                Next wBook

                If rFound Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "No open file for Cvent003 Meetings Found. Make sure the most recent Cvent003 Excel WB is open!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
                    Exit Sub
                End If
```

Comment: What is your problem? I can't see question in your question.

Comment: `Set rFound = wSheet.Range("D1:D2").Find(What:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Range("A2"), SearchFormat:=True, After:=wSheet.Range("D1"), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)`
This is the code that I'm using, I was able to have the Find value be looked up in a cell. Now, I want the to change the `After` in a similar way! I'm sorry, I think I'm not very clear, but I hope you all help me like always.
@EganWolf

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I understand what you wrote about `What` argument, that it's taken from a cell. And now you want to do the same for `After` argument? What do you mean? In `After` you need a range, to setup a start position for searching. How do you want to have it dynamic?

Comment: @EganWolf, yes I want the range to be basically user editable. I've added another sheet called "Data Specs" in `ThisWorkbook` and I'll enter the range in one of the cells in this sheet. For example, `After:=wSheet.RangeThisWorkbook.Sheets(Data Specs").Range("B2").Value)` and the cell `B2` has a value `"D1"`. I tried this code, but it didn't work, any thoughts? If this works, I plan to do a similar setup for the part `wSheet.Range("D1:D2")`

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
After:=wSheet.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Range("B2").Value)
```

You need to pass a `Range` object to `After` parameter. That's why the value from cell `B2` has to be used as argument of `Range` method.

EDIT:

Try to set this range to variable and then use it in `After`:

```
Set afterRange = wSheet.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Range("B2").Value)
```

And in `Find` method:

```
After:=afterRange
```

You can even try to assign `var = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Range("B2").Value` to a variable and use it in `Set afterRange = wSheet.Range(var)`

EDIT2:

I just made a full check for you with two workbooks, one for code and one with searched value. Everything was working just fine for me. I used this code:

```
Sub test()
Set wsheet = Workbooks("test2").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rfound = wsheet.Range("D1:D2").Find(What:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Range("A2"), SearchFormat:=True, _
                After:=wsheet.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Range("B2")), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)

rfound.Select
End Sub
```

And here's the result: [image: result]

Code is run from master.xslm and Data Specs is in master workbook. Searched values are in test2 in Sheet1. You can see in immediate window that value was found properly.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I tried this, but its jumping to the `MsgBox` - nothing found; somehow not taking that `Range` defined in the cell into consideration. :(
@EganWolf

Comment: I checked it and it was working for me, so it is possible to do it in that way. Maybe I messed up some of your sheet names? Is it working if you use `wSheet.Range("D2")`?

Comment: You can also type `?ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Range("B2").Value` in the immediate window while debugging to check if the value is recognized properly.

Comment: Ya, it works perfectly if I use `"D1"` there. The sheet name is also correct; I have the value `"D1"` entered in the cell. I tried debugging it, not really sure about this statement - `?ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Specs").Range("B2").Value`

Comment: Alright., I tried printing the value and it is giving me `"D1"` which is correct and ideally should work, but just giving up on me! :(

Comment: If I try the above mentioned technique, I defined `afterRange` as `Range` and now I get an error - `Object variable or With block variable not set`

Comment: @AkshaySachdev Check it again. I don't think there is anything more I can do.

Comment: You are a Star!! I wonder why it didn't work for me the other day, maybe I was too tired with all this code, but it worked like a charm today! I'll finally be presenting my work. Thanks a million..